# Where can I find GI GUI for Mac with same interface as windows

Tags: git, macos, git-gui

I have GIT GUI installed on my Mac, I installed 2 years back & it has same interface as windows. My friend is trying to install on his Mac but we are not able to find the same interface like http://msysgit.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Git GUI is not available as a separate package.  You can, however, install a newer Git for Mac via [the Mac download page on git-scm.com](http://git-scm.com/download/mac).  It has both Gitk and Git GUI in there.